# Why isn't the filter() method properly hiding unwanted rows?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

For context, we have a spreadsheet template to organize all the different orders the company receives. The idea is that we just select the client and the quantity of each product, then we click the create quote sheet button on the custom menu. Everything is fine. The sheet is successfully copied with a unique reference code, the correct client details and the correct name. However the filtering of the products is giving me trouble. I tried using the filter() method however it simply does nothing. No errors or anything, it just doesn't filter. Here is what I think is the relevant code:

```
    // declare that the copy is now the active spreadsheet
    var sheetId = quoteName.getId();
    var openQuoteSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId);
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(openQuoteSheet);  
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(openQuoteSheet.getSheets()[0]);
    var allProducts = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();  

    // filter out the products that the client doesn't need
    var fullSheet = allProducts.getRange('D15:D48').getValues();
    Logger.log(fullSheet);
    fullSheet.filter(checkQuantity);
    openQuoteSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    filteredProducts = fullSheet.filter(checkQuantity);
    function checkQuantity(amount){ return amount > 0;}
    Logger.log(filteredProducts);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fullSheet` is a 2 D array.  Therefor each element of `checkQuantity` is a row of the array.  I'm assuming you want to compare the first column of each row with 0.

Change:

```
function checkQuantity(amount){ return amount > 0;}
```

To:

```
function checkQuantity(amount){ return amount[0] > 0;}
```

Comment: Your answer works when I try to console log it, however the spreadsheet is still not filtered. I also tried making it a 1 D array, since, like you made me realize, it was a 2 D one . However that also doesn't work. Maybe I am doing something wrong and mixed up the columns?

Comment: You are putting the `filteredProducts` back to the Spreadsheet using `setValues()`?

Comment: I am trying to put filteredProducts into a copy spreadsheet, which I set as the active one beforehand, using setValues(). Maybe that's what's causing the malfunction?

Comment: I don't use all those `setActive` things.  I specify the sheet using `getSheetByName` the range `getRange(i,j,k,l)` and so forth.  That way I know exactly where things come from or where they go.

Comment: I see, thank you very much, I will try to see if that helps in debugging.

Comment: It works! this has been such a pain to fix, thank you so much!